# SQL query to return true/false by updating/inserting record according to record exists and with one condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which saves time stamp value associated with primary_keys of the record.

Table : primary_key_timestamp

Column : primary_key VARCHAR(40), time_stamp (TIMESTAMP).

I need a single query which updates the timestamp value of a primary key and return `true` in following cases :

1. Entry not exist for provided key : Insert it and return true.
2. Entry exist and timestamp value in table is lesser than value provided : Update it and return True.

Should return `false` in following case :

1. Timestamp already exist for key and it has higher timestamp value : Dont do anything just return false.

Comment: See INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry... I have handled the above case with following query.
```INSERT INTO primary_key_timestamp (primary_key,timestamp)
values (?,?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
primary_key = VALUES(primary_key),
  timestamp = IF( VALUES(timestamp) > timestamp,VALUES(timestamp),timestamp)
 ;
```

Please post this as answer.

Comment: It's too trivial - but feel free to post and accept yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to insert and return a result in a single statement, unless you're calling a stored procedure. If you are able to get `ROW_COUNT()` after the insert (which many drivers/clients will do implicitly), you can find out if this query makes any updates. Just check for a nonzero row count.

```
INSERT INTO primary_key_timestamp (primary_key, time_stamp)
VALUES ([your_key], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time_stamp = GREATEST(time_stamp, VALUES(time_stamp));
```

If you want to set `time_stamp` to a custom value, just replace `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` with your value.

Comment: @Strawberry, please provide a source. Either way, the downvote seems a bit extreme.

Comment: @Strawberry You're linking a SO question about PHP's MySQL driver as proof that insert queries have a return value??

Comment: @Strawberry Highly. OP didn't mention that he's using PHP, or any other client for that matter. He asked about MySQL. If you read my answer, I'm addressing the question from a pure MySQL perspective, though I also mention that some drivers may implement a return value under the hood.